# How should a setter be written with a constant variable inside a class?

Tags: c++

I'm a **newbie** in developing with C++. 
I get an error in "this->Buchtitel = buchtitel;" and can't understand why. I have to use const when initializing the variables in Book.h. The Error-Code is: E0349

Book.h

```
std::string const Buchtitel;
std::string const Autor;
std::string const Anschaffungsdatum;
bool const Status;
```

Book.cpp

```
void Book::setBuchtitel(std::string buchtitel) {
   this->Buchtitel = buchtitel;
}
void Book::setAutor(std::string autor) {
    this->Autor = autor;
}
void Book::setAnschaffungsdatum(std::string anschaffungsdatum) {
    this->Anschaffungsdatum = anschaffungsdatum;
}
void Book::setStatus(bool status) {
    this->Status = status;
}
```

How should "setBuchtitel" be written so it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: You can't change the value of something that is `const`.  So you either need to remove the `const` or remove the setters

Comment: ***The Error-Code is: E0349*** Not everyone memorizes error codes. Also many people don't use the same compiler as you. It is preferred to add the exact text of the error message. In Visual Studio its best to copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab not the errors list. The output tab is in a better text format.

Comment: Note: Don't write setters for everything. Only write setters when the world outside the class has a reasonable need to set the member. And when you do write a setter,  it should have some sort of added value such as protecting the object from being damaged by invalid values or triggering an event, such as re-computing another member, on change. If the member can always be set and setting the member has no other effect, the value is `public` in all but name and needs to be treated like a `public` member. Maybe it should be a `public` member.

Comment: A lot of the time, probably most of the time, you should be providing the value of the member during construction and have no setter whatsoever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a `const` variable can only be set during initialization of the variable. For a member variable that's as a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

```
std::string const Buchtitel = "Das Boot";
```

or in the constructor's [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

```
book(string titel): Buchtitel{titel}
{
}
```

The value cannot be set anywhere else. In this case the default member initializer is next to useless to you because if it is used exclusively, all books will have the same title.

This makes writing a setter for a `const` member variable impossible.

Comment: I'll talk to my professor and ask him what he ment with "make your variables const"

Comment: @F0xWhite A book's title, author, etc... is unlikely to change after the books is added to the system, so they have an excellent case for being `const`. And because they are unlikely to change, a setter will almost never be used even should you make the member variables non-`const`. If the instructor requires `const` member and setters, you must discuss with the instructor and get clarification. Otherwise, I'd leave out the setters.

Comment: Side note: A general rule of thumb is to make everything as restrictive as possible until you are forced to open them up. Taking this advice all the way suggests all variables should be immutable, `const`, unless they need to be changed. While it can be annoying, this prevents accidents.